# Rolling sum in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, dataset

I have an cross-sectional array with columns as prices for each date. I want to create another array with a rolling sum for window of 30 days. I would prefer not to use a for loop.
Currently, I am using the following code for one column:

```
for i=31:n
 for j=i-30:i-1
  x = x + y(j)
 end
sum(i) = x
end
```

I need to this for all securities and thus the code will have to run multiple times for all elements in a dataset.

Comment: whatever you do, don't use `sum` as a name of a variable, you are overwriting matlab's built in `sum` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `cumsum`'s!

```
data = 1:10;
n = length(data);
window = 3;
rollSum = cumsum(data)-[zeros(1,window), cumsum(data(1:n-window))];
rollSum =

 1     3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27

1=1
1+2=3
1+2+3=6
  2+3+4=9
    3+4+5=12
```

Answer (score 4):

For each column `x`, You can convolve with a sequence of 30 ones, and then remove the initial and final transients:

```
N = 30;
y = conv(x,ones(N,1));
y = y(N:end-N+1);
```

If `X` is a matrix, you can similarly process all columns at the same time:

```
y = conv2(ones(N,1),1,X);
y = y(N:end-N+1,:);
```

Comment: i still would have to run a outer loop is it possible to use the entire array and pass a function to all elements in it such that it makes first 30 elements 0 and the 31 onwards all are sum of last 30 elements

Comment: i have searched and found arrayfun/ cellfun, which may solve the problem. But i have no idea how to use them

Comment: using `conv` is the solution you want. Actually, it is enough to write:  `y=zeros(size(x)); y(30:end) = conv(x,ones(1,30),'valid');` to get the zeros padded from the left

Comment: @natan Yeah, I seemed to remember the 'valid' option. But I'm using R2007a right now and the 'valid' option does not exist. I thought I was remembering incorrectly, but now I see it has to do with my version

Comment: @natan The weird thing is, R2007a is the _highest_ version I have used until a few days ago. So I think 'valid' existed in previous versions and then was removed...?

Comment: `conv` was changed in MATLAB 7.8 (R2009a). I don't really know about this before 2007... see also http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/MatlabVersionsCompatibility.

Answer (score 3):

This can be very easy with `filter`.

Suppose you have a simple vector of ones:

```
x = ones(100,1);
```

Then we just a apply a filter on it like so:

```
filter(ones(1,30),1,x)
```

This also works if `x` is a matrix, for example `ones(100,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Matlab 2016a there is command `movsum`

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movsum.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes