# Summing blocks of numbers in a vector in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to sum consecutive 96 value blocks in a vector of n (in one case 14112) values. The background is that the values are 15-min temperature measurements and I want to average 96 at a time (1 to 96, 96+1 to 2*96 ... n*96+1 to (n+1)*96)  to produce a daily average. This could of course be done in a loop stepping 96 but my question is if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this in Matlab.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142720/rolling-sum-in-matlab, but here it is blocks, not rolling

Comment: That question seems to take a vector of `N` and give an output of about length `N-k`, this question however, takes a vector of length `N` and gives an output of length `k`. Hence I wouldn't consider them to be duplicates.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was a duplicate but it's only similar. My bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `reshape` and `mean`:

```
data = randn(1,14112); % example data. Row vector
m = 96; % block size. It is assumed that m divides length(data)
result = mean(reshape(data,m,[]));
```

As @Dan points out, if the number of elements is not a multiple of the block size some padding is necessary. The following code, due to him, does the necessary padding in the last block while keeping the mean of that block. Thanks also to @DennisJaheruddin for his sugggestion not to modifiy original variable:

```
data = randn(1,14100); % example data. Row vector
m = 96; % block size
n = length(data);
result = mean(reshape([data repmat(mean(data(n-mod(n,m)+1:n)), 1, m - mod(n, m))], m, []));
```

Comment: 2 seconds before me ;) but you should include some sort fo padding at the end in case `n` doesn't divide by `96`

Comment: I suggest this: `m = 96;
n = length(data);
data(end:end + m - mod(n, m)) = mean(data(end-mod(n,m)+1:end))`

Comment: Sorry that should be `...data(end + 1:end + m - mod(n, m))...`

Comment: Note that this will change your input variable if ran in the same workspace.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin true, but very easy to work around

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks. Corrected, without using a second variable

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate way to nicely deal with the problem, it also works if the lenght of the data is not a nice multiple of the window size:

```
data = randn(1,14112); 
w = 96; 

N = numel(data);
M = NaN(w,ceil(N/w));
M(1:N) = data;
nanmean(M)
```

If you don't want to include partial days at the end, use `fix` instead of `ceil`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Also, it uses more memory than needed (`data` and `M` are essentially the same)

Comment: @LuisMendo True, but I am curious as to whether avoiding to assign your intermediate result to a variable really reduces the required memory. I am referring to this part: `reshape([data repmat(mean(data(n-mod(n,m)+1:n)), 1, m - mod(n, m))], m, [])`

Comment: Yes, Matlab might or might not internally build the extended variable. It would be interesting to know